# How to change Date Format in listview in backoffice

Tags: listview, sap-commerce-cloud, cockpit, backoffice

I am trying to change date format in hybris backoffice listview and I wanted to display in dd/MM/yyyy format. Any help on this please.

[image: Date format for Last Ship Date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trails I found the following solution.
To change the date format in listview, we can do it in the following way.

```
<context parent="GenericItem" type="AbstractOrder" component="listview">
  <list-view:list-view>
    <list-view:column qualifier="code" />
    <list-view:column qualifier="focusOrderNumber" />
    <list-view:column qualifier="date.getMonth()+1+'/'+date.getDate()+'/'+date.getYear()+1900)" label="type.AbstractOrder.date.name"/>
    <list-view:column qualifier="totalPrice" />
    <list-view:column qualifier="shipToUnit"/>
    <list-view:column qualifier="user" />
  </list-view:list-view>
</context>
```

**Note:** You can specify any delimiter in place of /. 
**Note:** The only problem with this approach is we can't add prefix 0 when date or month less than 10.

It helped me. I hope it may help others too.

Answer (score 0):

The listview as an own configuration file. I think it calls something like 'xxx_listview.xml' (xxx = depends on which kind of model you are working). And there I think you can define an editor how some attributes shold be displayed. maybe you have to write your own editor an than put the reference in here.